# System.out.println() not working

Tags: java

this is my first post. I am excited to a part of this community and I have been struggling with this problem for a while, so here goes:

In the following code:

```
if (j == 0)
      {
        if (!Arrays.equals(cipherData, c))
        {
          System.out.print("C: ");
          for (int i = 0; i < encryptedData.length; i++)
            System.out.print((char)cipherData[i]);
          System.out.println();
        }
      }
```

The `System.out.println()`
method returns nothing at all. No line, or anything and I have no idea why. The goal is to print a blank line after printing the byte array is printed above when those if conditions are true.

Any help would be much appreciated and welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.out.print()` does not print a newline character.

You're outputting a bunch of stuff, then printing a newline with `System.out.println()`. This causes  the cursor to drop to the next line.

You need another one if you want a blank line after that.

**Edit to add:** I missed the fact that your `for` loop conditional is ... different than the array you're printing. Did you mean for that to be the case?

Also, since you're possibly printing non-printable characters, it is completely plausible that you're causing the terminal to be in a state  where the newline will no longer work.

What it comes down to is, `println()` isn't broken. Either it's not getting called, or if you don't see a newline occur when it is called then the terminal is in a state where it no longer recognizes it.

Comment: There could be alternative if he uses System.out.println("\n"); Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The only issue there is if the system *doesn't* use `\n` as newline. Like an OS that rhymes with "Windows". There's actually a way to get the current system-specific newline character (`System.getProperty("line.separator")`) but ... just using `println()` again is easier.

Comment: Now this really made me curious. If system does not use \n then how come System.out.println() will work? I did no research so asking this to you.

Comment: The JVM is platform specific, it knows what the system's newline character is and  that's what `println()` will use. See the edit to my last comment - that's how you can retrieve it from the `System` class.

Comment: Thank you for the help, though it doesn't matter what I place within the System.out.println() method, including "\n" or anything else. Nothing prints unless I place the System.out.println() outside of the if satements. even when I create a whole other set of if statements with the same conditions and call System.out.println() not a thing happens.

Comment: @BrianRoach so if the terminal is in a state in which it no longer recognizes what it is called how should i fix it? and would it still be able to print outside of these if statements because it is.

Comment: Don't print non-printable characters. That's really the issue. Without your entire program, test data that reproduces it, and the debugger in front of me ... I really couldn't tell you *exactly* where and why things are happening. But that's pretty much the crux of what would cause it.

Comment: Okay so I have no idea why the different length of encryptedData and cipherData did not throw any error, however it was the issue. Thank you so, so much I don't even know how I missed that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Before iterating for loop you can check length of  encryptedData

System.out.println("encryptedData.length::  "+ encryptedData.length);

```
if encryptedData.length return greater than 1 then it will go into for loop.
You should debug step by step .
```

Comment: Im not exactly sure the significance, though it does not print either. Nothing prints in this call on System.out.println(); though if I place it outside of the if statements things print fine.

Comment: can u use  System.out.println((char)cipherData[i]);

Comment: yes the Byte array prints just fine. Its anything that I try to print after the for loop that prints the byte array that is still within the if statements that do not print. When stepping through the program line by line the System.out.println() method is completely skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Check

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println()

You may need `System.out.print('\n')`;

Comment: Thank you for the help, though it doesn't matter what I place within the System.out.println() method, including "\n" or anything else. Nothing prints.

Comment: @user1905765 have you confirmed that all your if and for conditions are getting true?

Comment: Yes the other print statement within the for loop prints

Answer (score 1):

I have concerns about this:

```
System.out.print((char)cipherData[i]);
```

Assuming that `cipherData` is an array of bytes, then casting a byte to a `char` and printing it via a character stream is not likely to give pretty results.  For a start, bytes that are less that 32 decimal will map to ASCII "control characters".

And also you may be printing the wrong array ... or using the length of the wrong array.

(But the explanation for your problem is that you need to call `println` a second time to be a blank line.  The first println is just terminating the line containing the ... umm ... "characters" from your cipher array.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the problem is that you have run a JVM without any standard output attached. Like on Windows, using javaw.exe to run a jar (which is the default, beware). Java.exe outputs to the console window, if you run it from a console, but javaw.exe does not. If you run the program from the file explorer window, even though you are using java.exe, you *still* won't get any standard out, because it's hidden by windows.

So, run the program in a command line window, and use java.exe, not javaw.exe.